# AWS Amplify & React - Module not found: Can't resolve '@aws-amplify/analytics'

Tags: reactjs, amazon-web-services, aws-amplify, aws-amplify-cli

I am trying to add Login functionality to a React app I'm building using Amplify and AWS Cognito, but when I add the following line in my Login.js file:

```
Import {Auth} from "aws-amplify-react";
```

and try to compile, I get the following error:

```
Failed to compile.

./node_modules/aws-amplify-react/lib-esm/Analytics/trackLifecycle.js
Module not found: Can't resolve '@aws-amplify/analytics' in 'my_react_path/node_modules/aws-amplify-react/lib-esm/Analytics'
```

I tried installing Amplify with homebrew and npm, but I can't get around this, any tips?

**EDIT:**

Initially I had:

```
Import {Auth} from "aws-amplify";
```

But The compiler couldn't resolve aws-amplify, and I could only find aws-amplify-react in the node_modules folder so I changed it.

However, in "node_modules/aws-amplify-react/lib-esm/Analytics/trackLifecycle.js" in line 39:

```
import Analytics from '@aws-amplify/analytics';
```

The problem is that it can't find aws-amplify... Did I make a mess while installing maybe?

Answer (score 5):

I get a similar error

> Failed to compile.
>
> ./node_modules/aws-amplify-react/lib-esm/Analytics/trackLifecycle.js
> Module not found: Can't resolve '@aws-amplify/analytics' in '/Users/myuser/myproject/node_modules/aws-amplify-react/lib-esm/Analytics'

when following the [Amplify tutorial](https://aws-amplify.github.io/docs/js/start#step-1-create-a-new-app).

The workaround I found is to execute:

> npm i -S @aws-amplify/analytics @aws-amplify/interactions @aws-amplify/storage @aws-amplify/ui @aws-amplify/xr aws-amplify

Obviously, I would love to know how to avoid all these extra libraries.

Comment: For those wondering about why there are multiple `@aws-amplify/*` packages, Amplify is moving to a more modularized structure. See their wiki article on it here: https://github.com/aws-amplify/amplify-js/wiki/Amplify-modularization. AWS isn't alone, as there is a trend toward modularization, and others such as [Expo](https://blog.expo.io/expo-sdk-34-is-now-available-4f7825239319) are moving to modular imports as well.

Answer (score 3):

Assuming that you are not worried about bundle size at this stage, probably your easiest course of action is to remove your node_modules entirely, then:

1. npm i aws-amplify
2. import like this:

```
import Amplify, { Auth } from 'aws-amplify'
```

You only need to install/import aws-amplify-react if you plan on using the OOTB UI components.  If you are making your own UI components for login you don't need that package at this stage.

Answer (score 0):

I would revert to your previous version before attempting to add amplify (old package.json & node_modules)

Follow this walkthrough: https://docs.amplify.aws/start/getting-started/installation/q/integration/react-native

When you get to the "Add Authentication" step, skip it and go straight to "Next Steps" -> "Authentication" and follow until you get to:

```
import Amplify, {Auth} from 'aws-amplify';
import config from './aws-exports';
Amplify.configure(config);
```

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar issue, but my error was about the **interactions** package inside **aws-amplify**.

I originally installed **aws-amplify** like this:

```
$ npm i aws-amplify
```

But it seems the above does not install specific packages, so I did this:

```
$ npm i aws-amplify/interactions
```

and it worked.